# Not able to write test class for this class. Error : testmethods do not support get content call

Tags: getcontent

```
global class sendPDFEmailClass
{

@AuraEnabled
    WebService static void emailPdf(ID opportunityId)
    {  
        PageReference pdfPage= Page.QuotationPDF;
        pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',opportunityId);

        Attachment attach = new Attachment();
        Blob pdf1 = pdfPage.getContent();

        Datetime now = Datetime.now();
        Integer offset = UserInfo.getTimezone().getOffset(now);
        Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);

        Opportunity currOpp = [Select Primary_Contact__r.Email from Opportunity where Id = :opportunityId]; 

        attach.Body = pdf1;
        attach.Name = 'Quotation_PDF '+local;
        attach.IsPrivate = false;
        attach.ParentId = opportunityId;

           try{
               insert attach;
           }
           catch(DMLException e)
           {
               system.debug('Exception caught '+e.getmessage());
           }


        Messaging.Singleemailmessage mail= new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {currOpp.Primary_Contact__r.Email};

        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment(); 
        efa.setFileName('Quotation' + '.pdf');

        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
        mail.setPlaintextbody('Quotation PDF');
        efa.setBody(pdf1 ); 
        //attach the PDF 
        mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});
        system.debug('Sending email'); 
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
     }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message suggests, `getContent` is not supported in test methods as it is also considered as a `webservice callout`. Hence you will have to make changes in your `sendPDFEmailClass` class so that your test methods skips that line and passes you a dummy content when tested from test class. So, in order to do that,  you will have to replace this below line in your main class

```
Blob pdf1 = pdfPage.getContent();
```

with

```
Blob pdf1; 
if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
  pdf1 = blob.valueOf('For Unit testing');
} else {
  pdf1 = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
}
```